# What is an effective way to map RGBW pixel data to RGB for a visualisation

Tags: colors, rgb, led

I'm developing software to control four channel LEDs with Red, Green, Blue and White channels (RGBW). The white channel is controlled independently from the RGB, so you may end up with values such as (255,255,255,0) or (0,0,0,255).

In my app there is a visualisation of how the LEDs will look, to be shown on a conventional RGB screen.

Colour accuracy is less important than ensuring things remain plausible. Until now, I've been mapping `(r,g,b,w) -> (3r+w, 3g+w, 3b+w)/4`. However this causes a pure white `(0,0,0,255)` value to come out dark grey `(63, 63, 63)`, which is confusing to the user.

Are there any ways to map my RGBW colours to RGB for display? (Interested in an equation or algorithm rather than a specific implementation.)

Comment: Are you using a certain language? Python and Nodejs both have OpenCV. You could write a conversion function, something like `red_channel=(red_component+white_component/3)/340` to get the percentage of red at that pixel. What are looking to do?

Comment: I'm in C++/Cinder but the question is more general regarding an effective way to represent the four channel colour in three channels for the UI.

Comment: You amy want to edit your question to include the language; the way it currently reads you are looking for an example implimentation...?

Comment: Ah that's not what I intended. I'm more looking for an algorithm or equation. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I've gone for. It's enough for particular case where offering something intuitive is more important than colour accuracy, but I'd still be interested in some more general solutions.

It's based on the observations that:

- The perception of introducing white into a colour is non-linear - adding a small amount when there is none is more noticable than adding a small amount when there is already plenty in the white channel.
- 60% white is enough to communicate that an LED is showing `(0,0,0,255)`.

What I do is:

- Calculate `w2` which is the white value with the gamma increased, calculated using an inverse square curve: `w2 = 1 - (1-w)^2`.
- Interpolate the RGB value towards a white value by a factor `alpha` defined as `0.6*w2`.

In code: given floats `r`,`g`,`b` and `w` in the range `[0, 1]`, define

```
w2 = (1.0 - (1.0 - w) * (1.0 - w))
alpha = 0.6 * w2
```

Then use this for the RGB colour:

```
[
  (1.0 - alpha) * r + alpha,
  (1.0 - alpha) * g + alpha,
  (1.0 - alpha) * b + alpha
]
```

Or in vector form:

```
out = (1.0 - alpha) * [r,g,b] + alpha * [1,1,1]
```

Comment: This looks promising, but does that mean that `[0,0,0,0]` comes out as `[1,1,1]` ?  
What is your `beta = 1 - a` supposed to do? (is `a` meant to be `alpha`, or another variable?)

Comment: @MrTrick Yes sorry there were mistakes in the implementation which I've now fixed, and also I've expanded on the explanation.